# Shell to display specific record from a file in a particular format

Tags: shell, scripting

Input File

```
GMDCOM.27936 [Tue Oct  1 13:32:40 2013]: Process Request <36812974>
GMDCOM.27936 [Tue Oct  1 13:37:38 2013]: Process Request <36812985>
GMDCOM.27936 [Tue Oct  1 13:37:53 2013]: Process Request <36812986>
GMDCOM.27936 [Tue Oct  1 13:37:54 2013]: Process Request <36812987>
GMDCOM.27936 [Tue Oct  1 13:37:57 2013]: Process Request <36812996>
```

I want the output in the below format.

```
36812974 [Tue Oct  1 13:32:40 2013]
36812985 [Tue Oct  1 13:37:38 2013]
36812986 [Tue Oct  1 13:37:53 2013]
```

and it goes on like this till the end of the file. How will it display all the records in the above format. Please help.

Comment: which shell are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` you could say:

```
sed -r 's/.*(\[.*\]).*<(.*)>/\2 \1/g' filename
```

For your input, it'd return:

```
36812974 [Tue Oct  1 13:32:40 2013]
36812985 [Tue Oct  1 13:37:38 2013]
36812986 [Tue Oct  1 13:37:53 2013]
36812987 [Tue Oct  1 13:37:54 2013]
36812996 [Tue Oct  1 13:37:57 2013]
```

Comment: How can I do it using AWK. and can you please explain the code you have written using SED.

Comment: `\1` and `\2` above are [backreferences](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Backreferences_002c-in-regular-expressions-103).

Comment: It can surely be done using `awk`; it wouldn't be as straight-forward, though.

Comment: Unable to understand the full SED code exactly. Please help me in understand since I am new to shell scripting and if possible to help me in getting the output using AWK.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you gave above
Here's a one liner or can be put in a script "bash" input.data= Your Filename or
process that you can pipe the output

cat input.data|cut -f2 -d "["| awk  -F"<" '{print $2, "["$1}'|tr -d '>'|cut -f1-3 -d ":"